# XmlListModel Syntax Error? Currency Converter

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I've followed the currency converter "Hello World" tutorial, as far as I can see exactly how it should. Yet when I try and run it via QMLScene I get a Syntax Error on line 45.

Line 45 is:

```
XmlListModel {
    id: ratesFetcher
    source: "http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"
    namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace gesmes='http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01';"
                       +"declare default element namespace 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref';"
    query: "/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube"

    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status === XmlListModel.Ready) {
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                currencies.append({"currency": get(i).currency, "rate": parseFloat(get(i).rate)})
        }
    }

    XmlRole { name: "currency"; query: "@currency/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "rate"; query: "@rate/string()" }
```

}

Any ideas what I've messed up here? This is the [link for complete code](http://pastebin.com/KPQw6THk).

Comment: Is it this tutorial ? http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/ If yes, it is not an "*Hello World!*" but a currency converter application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything should be inside the Rectangle { } block.  See http://paste.ubuntu.com/1540065/ for a working example.